# Is there a reason why SASS, a CSS generator, needs to reject lines such as margin:10px ? (no space after colon)

Tags: css, syntax, sass

I need to change all the CSS into SASS... and find that

```
margin:10px
```

working in CSS and failing in SASS somewhat disturbing...

It is easy to miss one and you don't what you are missing (what is not working in the final CSS but you don't know)

Pretty much I am grep for /:\S/ (colon by followed by a non-whitespace) to see if there are such cases, using TextMate (a Mac text editor)... but those a:hover also shows up as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sass you can define nested selectors, and these can have pseudoclasses such as :hover. It doesn't see your margin as an attribute but as another element with a pseudoclass.

```
.stylin
  display: block
  margin:10px
  a:hover
    color: red
```

The above will recognize `display: block` correctly, but it will see `margin:10px` and `a:hover` as the same kind of pattern.

Comment: but I think if the CSS parser is smart enough to tell the difference, the SASS parser should be able to too

Comment: @動靜能量: There are no nested selectors in CSS, so the CSS parser doesn't tell the difference either. If you want more similarity with CSS, then use SCSS syntax: it has more punctuation, so it can be more forgiving about whitespace.