# SASS: Why does phpsass remove the css attribute -webkit-box?

Tags: css, sass

I am using PHPSASS in my web project. After running the whole thing I noticed that it removed all occurences of `display:-webkit-box` in my css. Why that?

Comment: Removed from the generated CSS or just not displaying as a property in your CSS debugger/console?  The online PHPSASS compiler (http://phpsass.com/try/) doesn't seem to be removing a `-webkit-box` property when it compiles.  I could not find a `box` property when I googled it (I was trying to find out what value it expects).  Browsers ignore properties they don't understand, so they won't appear in the debugger/console.

Comment: @cimmanon You were right. My question was not precise enough. I meant occurences `display:-webkit-box`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Problem is not with the value (-webkit-box) it's because of the missing space before it!
see: [Is there a reason why SASS, a CSS generator, needs to reject lines such as margin:10px ? (no space after colon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040817/is-there-a-reason-why-sass-a-css-generator-needs-to-reject-lines-such-as-margi?rq=1)